# Как реализовать окно ожидание создания архива перед скачкой?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, download

Есть страничка с списком файлов, в котором пользователь может отметить файлы для скачки. По нажатию на кнопку "скачать" отправляется POST форма на туже страницу, на которой выполняется следующий скрипт:

```
    private function multiDownload($data)
    {
        // logger
        try {
            $audioFiles = AudioFileModel::findAll([
                'id' => ['in' => $data['multi-download']],
                'status' => AudioFileModel::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                'order by' => 'prior',
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!SystemHelper::is_dir($this->tmp_path)) {
            SystemHelper::mkdir($this->tmp_path);
        }

        // generate unique archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $count = 0;
        do {
            if ($count > 10) {
                // can`t generate unique archive
                $log->write('Can`t generate unique archive filename!');
                return false;
            }
            $name = md5(microtime() . rand(0, 9999));
            $filename = $this->tmp_path.$name.'.zip';
            $count++;
        } while ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE ) !== true);

        // add files to archive
        foreach($audioFiles as $audioFile) {
            $zip->addFile(SystemHelper::preparePath($audioFile->getPath(false)), Conv::win2zip($audioFile->file));
        }
        // save archive
        if ($zip->close() !== true) {
            $log->write('Archive hasn`t create, '.print_r($zip->getStatusString(), true));
            return false;
        }

        //then send the headers to force download the zip file
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$audioFile->getPlaylist()->title." ".$audioFile->getPlaylist()->subtitle.".zip\"");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

        ob_end_clean();
        readfile($filename);

        // remove archive
        SystemHelper::unlink($filename)ж

        return true;
    }
```

После выполнения скрипта, пользователь остается на страницы, и без перезагрузки у него всплывает окно сохранения файла.

Когда пользователь выбирает много файлов, то архив создается около 10сек. Как предоставить пользователю информацию о том что архив создается?

Как запустить какую нибудь анимацию загрузки по нажатию на кнопку и по окну скачки остановить анимацию?

Comment: Судя по всему форму вы аяксом шлете, ваш серверный код не актуален для задачи (в нем всеравно не получится вывести ничего). Если используете jQuery $.ajax то лоудер можно показывать на beforeSend и скрывать на complete

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Нет, без AJAX сейчас все работает. Если использовать AJAX то скажите как через него реализовать скачку, так что бы после скачки файл удалялся как сейчас?